# What is doubling time of tumor? (Using exponential growth)

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

So here is the question i received:

The rate of growth of a tumor is directly proportional to the size of the tumor. If the tumor is $5mm$ across at the time $t=0$ and is $8mm$ across $3$ months later, what is the doubling time?

I think I solved it but I need to make sure I did it correctly. Here is how I got my solution.
$$y(t)=t+5$$

So to find the doubling time I set that equation equal to $10$ 
$$10=t+5\implies t=5$$

Would that be correct on how I got to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it linear growth or exponential growth?

Comment: @Fmonkey2001 Im going to assume it is exponential growth considering that is what we have been working on in class.

Comment: Then you will need to solve for $r$ first and then you'll be able to solve for the time it'll take to double.

Comment: Using $A=Pe^{rt}$

Comment: Check my answer below. I believe I have fixed it to give us the correct answer. The first time I did it I got a much smaller answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's exponential growth it'd be $$N(t)=N(0)e^{rt}$$ 
So we can solve for $r$: $$r={\ln({N(t)-N(0)})\over t}$$
So we know $N(0)=5$ and $N(3)=8$ so now we have $$r={{\ln(8)-\ln(5)}\over3}$$
Now we can say that $$2=e^{{{\ln(8)-\ln(5)}\over3}t}$$We can take the natural log of each side and simplify a little to get:$$\ln2={\ln(3)\over 3}t$$ solving for $t$ give us that:$$t={3\ln(2)\over {{\ln(8)-\ln(5)}}}=4.42430954207$$